# Is there a way to keep a notification on the screen from a backgrounded iOS app, similar to Apple's Timer app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer, notifications, background

There has been a lot written about how an app other than one using locations or playing music, for example, will be terminated after 30 seconds if it's in the background. The Apple Timer app isn't really a music app, but it does play a "tune" (alarm) forever once it's triggered, so I assume it's using the music framework. More interestingly, it also puts up a notification from the background that sticks to the top of the screen until the user taps it.

I'm writing an app that requires an alarm of exactly this type: One that keeps sounding an alarm until the user responds. However, I can't see how to keep a notification on the screen. It disappears in about six seconds, and I can't find a setting that allows it to persist longer. The presence of the notification is important since tapping it brings up the app and quickly stops the alarm, without the user needing to potentially hunt for the correct icon on their device.

Since Apple has done this with the Timer app, I'd hope this would be possible for developers to emulate.

This is my code for putting up the notification. Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
[[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
}];
content = [UNMutableNotificationContent new];
content.title = @"Wake up!";
content.body = @"It's time to get up.";
content.sound = nil;
center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:@"NOTIFICATIONIDENTIFIER" content:content trigger:nil];
[center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

The trouble with your reasoning here is that You are not Apple. You say

> The Apple Timer app ... I'm writing an app that requires an alarm of exactly this type

No. You *cannot* do exactly what the Apple Clock app does with its timer. Apple has powers you do not have.

What you want to look at for prior art is something like the Multitimer app (https://apps.apple.com/us/app/multitimer-multiple-timers/id973421278). It demonstrates quite clearly the limits of what you can do.

> However, I can't see how to keep a notification on the screen. It disappears in about six seconds, and I can't find a setting that allows it to persist longer

That's not up to you either. It's up to the *user*. That's what the temporary-vs-persistent banner style is about:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/notifications/notificationsettingsitem

It may be that Apple's Timer app has the ability to force a persistent banner onto the user, but you do not.